# django: prevent UniqueTogetherValidator on Serializer

Tags: python, django, api, django-validation

I'm having a problem with django. I created my model with some fields like so:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    field3 = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('field1', 'field2'))
```

And I have an API route, which links to a model serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
```

The problem is that when I send objects via the API to update them, the serializer raises `{'non_field_errors': ['The fields field1, field2 must make a unique set.']}`

Does anyone know how to prevent `UniqueTogetherValidator` to be used on the serializer?

Comment: Is this error applicable to all the data you're sending or just one set? It looks more like the unique constraint is not being respected by the data. More so, `unique_together = ('field1', 'field2')` should look like so, without the double brackets

Comment: I'm sending a list with 6-24 objects, and I;m getting the error for every one of them. When I delete previous objects with those properties from the DB, the request succeeds. I'm tried removing the double parenthesis, the error remains

Comment: Every time you complete a request, you need to run `python manage.py flush` to clean the DB, if you're planning to use the exact same data again for another request. Else, you'll have a unique constraint violation.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I unerstand. However, I'm updating objects from an online interface, and all I need is getting them after the serializer so I can use a `get_or_create` in order to update/create them, but I never reach it because the serializer uses the `UniqueTogetherValidator`...

Comment: Try `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False)` as seen [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#raising-an-exception-on-invalid-data)

Comment: I really thought it wold work :( haha but it did not... If I find how to I'll post the answer here

Answer (score 1):

This is based off of `djangorestframework==3.8.2`. 
Override the `get_validators` method that is on `ModelSerializer` and comment out the call for getting the `unique_together_validators` if that is the only validator you really care about omitting. Otherwise this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022282/1658745 suggests just settings validators to empty list to turn off all validation for that serializer.

```
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    def get_validators(self):
        """
        Determine the set of validators to use when instantiating serializer.
        """
        # If the validators have been declared explicitly then use that.
        validators = getattr(getattr(self, 'Meta', None), 'validators', None)
        if validators is not None:
            return validators[:]

        # Otherwise use the default set of validators.
        return (
            # self.get_unique_together_validators() +
            self.get_unique_for_date_validators()
        )

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
```