# Django Rest Framework model serializer with out unique together validation

Tags: django, python-2.7, serialization, django-rest-framework, unique

I have a model with some fields and a `unique together`:

```
....
class Meta(object):
    unique_together = ('device_identifier', 'device_platform',)
```

Obviously, in this way, about Django rest framework serializer, I obtain an error when I try to make a PUT with the same `device_identifier` and `device_platform` (if already exist an entry with this data).

```
{
  "non_field_errors": [
    "The fields device_identifier, device_platform must make a unique set."
  ]
}
```

Is possible to disable this validation in my model serializer?
Because I need to manage this situation during save model step (for me, in serializer validation this is not an error)

Answer (score 41):

Django REST framework applies the `UniqueTogetherValidator` on the serializer. You can remove this by override the `validators` field in the serializer definition.

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        validators = []
```

Note that this also removes the other [unique-check validators](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/) that are applied on the model, which might not be the best idea. To avoid that, just override the `get_unique_together_validators` method on the serializer, to ensure only unique-together check is removed.

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_unique_together_validators(self):
        """Overriding method to disable unique together checks"""
        return []
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the validator from the serializer's list.

Although not exactly the same, the steps are explained [here](https://medium.com/django-rest-framework/dealing-with-unique-constraints-in-nested-serializers-dade33b831d9)