# Django Rest Framework - how to handle update of an item with order field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my DRF app, I've got this model :

```
class Item(models.Model):
    label = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField()
    order = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
        unique_together = ['order', 'category ']
```

I am looking for a way to update an instance, possibly changing his order value, and keep the ordering sequence correct.

Currently, the serializer validation failed because of the unique_together. But I don't want to update my DB before checking that the data are corrects...

Any idea on how to do that ?
Thanks a lot
Swann

Comment: You want the user to be able to move an Item and then increment/decrement all the other rows that need to be changed in 1 query?

Comment: Yes, but it could be in more than 1 query.

Comment: First you need to disable the validation on your serialiser https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022282/548562

Comment: I've just done that, but now I don't know how to write the save close, any update I tried until now failed miserably on unicity.

Comment: Do you mind having "gaps" in the order? (1,2, 4, 5)?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to disable the unique_together validator on your serializer to pass validation as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022282/548562

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_unique_together_validators(self):
        """Overriding method to disable unique together checks"""
        return []
```

Then you can override the `update` method to perform your re-ordering. This will leave gaps in the order though

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.label = validated_data.get('label', instance.label)
    instance.category = validated_data.get('category', instance.category)
    instance.order = validated_data.get('order', instance.order)
    if Item.objects.exclude(pk=instance.pk, category=instance.category, order=instance.order).exists():
        # If an item already exists with the same order and category shift all
        # Items up by 1 before saving
        Item.objects.filter(category=instance.category, order__gte=instance.order).order_by('-order').update(order=F('order') + 1)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

If you don't want gaps then it becomes a little more complicated as an `Item` could change category, you'd want to shift items in the old category down. If an item stays in the same category but it's order is increased you would want to shift all the items in-between down

Comment: I've just tried your solution, but the update failed : MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '3-2' for key ...")

Comment: I've tried with a order clause, but same result : Item.objects.filter(category=instance.category, order__gte=instance.order).update(order=F('order') + 1).order_by('-order')

Comment: I've seen my mistake after posting (I didn't copy past and misplaced the order_by).  Item.objects.filter(category=instance.category, order__gte=instance.order).order_by('-order').update(order=F('order') + 1) still send the exception IntegrityError

Comment: It's like django doesn't use the order_by clause by the way...